# Hadoop NoClassDefFoundError when adding external Jar

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, noclassdeffounderror, distributed-cache

I am trying to run a MapReduce job on Hadoop with an external Jar. I have added the Jar to the HDFS using `copyFromLocal` to `/user/hduser/lib/`.

In my main method, I add the Jar to the DistributedCache. However, when I run the MapReduce program I receive a NoClassDefFoundError in the Mapper class. I have tried many of the solutions posted on SO from others who've had a similar error however I have not resolved the issue. Any guidance is appreciated.

From Main Method:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
String jarToAdd1 = "/user/hduser/lib/joda-time-2.9.1-no-tzdb.jar";
String jarToAdd2 = "/user/hduser/lib/joda-time-2.9.1.jar";
addJarToDistributedCache(jarToAdd1, conf);
addJarToDistributedCache(jarToAdd2, conf);
.........
```

Adding to Distributed Cache:

```
private static void addJarToDistributedCache(String jarToAdd, Configuration conf) throws IOException {

        Path hdfsJar = new Path(jarToAdd);
        DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(hdfsJar,conf);
    }
```

Mapper Where Error Occurs:

```
public static class Map1 extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, UserData> {

Map<IntWritable, UserData> userLog = new HashMap<IntWritable, UserData>();

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String line = value.toString();                             
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);      
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyddmm HH:mm:ss");    // *********ERROR HAPPENS HERE **********
```

StackTrace:

```
16/01/30 20:45:15 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/01/30 20:45:16 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
16/01/30 20:45:16 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
16/01/30 20:45:16 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
16/01/30 20:45:16 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
16/01/30 20:45:16 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
16/01/30 20:45:16 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:3
16/01/30 20:45:17 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local1787244132_0001
16/01/30 20:45:17 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1454204717451/joda-time-2.9.1-no-tzdb.jar <- /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/joda-time-2.9.1-no-tzdb.jar
16/01/30 20:45:17 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/lib/joda-time-2.9.1-no-tzdb.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1454204717451/joda-time-2.9.1-no-tzdb.jar
16/01/30 20:45:17 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1454204717452/joda-time-2.9.1.jar <- /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/joda-time-2.9.1.jar
16/01/30 20:45:17 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/lib/joda-time-2.9.1.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1454204717452/joda-time-2.9.1.jar
16/01/30 20:45:17 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1454204717451/joda-time-2.9.1-no-tzdb.jar
16/01/30 20:45:17 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1454204717452/joda-time-2.9.1.jar
16/01/30 20:45:17 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
16/01/30 20:45:17 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_local1787244132_0001
16/01/30 20:45:17 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1787244132_0001_m_000000_0
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/input/sentimentFeedback7.csv:0+143748596
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1787244132_0001_m_000001_0
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/input/allergyConsumption7.csv:0+134217728
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1787244132_0001_m_000002_0
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/input/allergyConsumption7.csv:134217728+105486421
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
16/01/30 20:45:18 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local1787244132_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat
    at org.peach.fooddiary.FoodDiaryMR$Map1.map(FoodDiaryMR.java:45)
    at org.peach.fooddiary.FoodDiaryMR$Map1.map(FoodDiaryMR.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.DelegatingMapper.run(DelegatingMapper.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:784)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 12 more
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1787244132_0001 running in uber mode : false
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/01/30 20:45:18 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1787244132_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
16/01/30 20:45:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly  DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath is now deprecated, but instead you could use:

```
    Configuration conf = getConf();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "My Job Name");
    job.addFileToClassPath(new Path("path"));
```

Still have you faced the same problem, do it manually, I mean do the following to deploy your code to hadoop itself by putting your jar file(s) into hadoop's classpath:

1) Export your classes that need to be executed into hadoop using the following:

- In Project Explorer, Right click the project name and choose "Export..."
- Under "Java" section, Choose "Jar file" then "Next"
- Choose a directory into which you are gonna store your exported "jar"

2) Go to the server which is running hadoop and run the following to know what are directories that hadoop is looking inside, one of the examples are 
"$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/*"

```
$ hadoop classpath
```

3) Copy the exported jar file from step 1 to one of directories that you've got in step 2 then start test it again.

**Hint** It is better to test out map reduce in your server directly and run it inside your server using the following command:

```
$ hadoop jar JarFileName.jar PakageName.ClassName /path/to/input /path/to/output
```

For a complete example with detailed description, please check [this](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html)